# Is there any way to make div vertically on middle whenever even has changes of height?

Tags: jquery, css, html

im trying to make menu vertically on middle in header div. But this menu has  changes of height in Jquery because of  slideUp and slideDown.
So is there any way automatically on middle even if height changes with click event???

Answer (score 0):

The two following options should work. The first is simpler, but the second is more foolproof.

---

> **OPTION 1**

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="center"></div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#center {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%; }
```

---

> **OPTION 2**

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="middle">
<div class="inner">

<h1>The Content</h1>

<p>Once upon a midnight dreary...</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: /*whatever width you want*/;
}
```

Comment: if your JQuery is changing the height element, these should work. It would help if you could post some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope it will help you:-

```css
        header{
            background-color: #ccc;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        ul {
            text-align: center;
            }
        ul li{
            height: 40px;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding:0 10px;
            }
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>navigation</li>
                <li>navigation</li>
                <li>navigation</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```